# wso2dss 3.2.2 try this service is not responding

Tags: apache-axis, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

Iam working with wso2dss 3.2.2 version.
I have created a Data Service interacting with PostgreSQL database,This dataservice has a simple select operation and tried to test the data service by passing the parameters

Dataservice:

```
<data name="partyclientiddataservice" serviceNamespace="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
   <config id="default">
      <property name="carbon_datasource_name">USCProduction</property>
   </config>
   <query id="Select_Clientid_Op" useConfig="default">
      <sql>select clientid,clientname from mclient where clientcode=?</sql>
      <result element="Entries" rowName="Entry">
         <element column="clientid" name="clientid" xsdType="string"/>
         <element column="clientname" name="clientname" xsdType="string"/>
      </result>
      <param name="clientcode" sqlType="STRING"/>
   </query>
   <operation name="Select_Clientid_Op">
      <call-query href="Select_Clientid_Op">
         <with-param name="clientcode" query-param="clientcode"/>
      </call-query>
   </operation>
</data>
```

Am passing the required clientcode as shown in the below pic. 
[image]

Nothing is happening am not getting any response in the response side or any error in the dss server,But when the same service is called by any wso2esb proxy its working fine and getting response in the esb services.

Comment: do you see any exeptions in the console? what's the browser you are using? try with a different browser and see.

Comment: Hi Rajeev i was trying this in Mozilla firfox and i have now tried it in chrome browser and its working fine,No idea what is the problem with fire fox,Thanks a lot.